# How do i stack a title and a subtitle below it?

Tags: html, css

I'm an aspiring web developer and this is the first challenge that I'm facing, Chat GPT couldn't help me either on this one, everything that I've tried so far has failed. So, what I'm trying to do here is make the "2004, 21 songs, 1 h 16 min" be positioned below the title "The College Dropout" and of course to be aligned, to create a Spotify alike layout when you are searching for an album [webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rp83E.png).

I have tried changing the flex display to block, but it doesn't anything and if I try to change everything else like the flex display it makes the website unresponsive I think. Please, help me.

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Hiragino;
  src: url(../assets/fonts/hiragino-kaku-gothic.otf);
}

:root {
  --step--2: clamp(0.56rem, calc(0.48rem + 0.41vw), 0.8rem);
  --step--1: clamp(0.68rem, calc(0.56rem + 0.56vw), 1rem);
  --step-0: clamp(0.81rem, calc(0.66rem + 0.76vw), 1.25rem);
  --step-1: clamp(0.98rem, calc(0.77rem + 1.02vw), 1.56rem);
  --step-2: clamp(1.17rem, calc(0.9rem + 1.36vw), 1.95rem);
  --step-3: clamp(1.4rem, calc(1.04rem + 1.8vw), 2.44rem);
  --step-4: clamp(1.69rem, calc(1.21rem + 2.38vw), 3.05rem);
  --step-5: clamp(2.02rem, calc(1.4rem + 3.12vw), 3.82rem);
}

html {
  background-color: white;
}

.container {
  background: rgb(65, 18, 24);
  background: linear-gradient( 0deg, rgba(65, 18, 24, 1) 0%, rgba(232, 152, 46, 1) 100%);
  padding-top: 2rem;
  padding-bottom: 5rem;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: right;
  list-style: none;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}

li {
  margin: 0 10px;
}

a {
  color: grey;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: Hiragino;
  font-size: 0.7rem;
}

a:hover {
  color: white;
}


/* Responsive styles */

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  ul {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  li {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }
}

.image-container {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 2rem;
  align-items: center;
}

.image-style {
  width: clamp(200px, 50%, 400px);
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.image-container .title-style {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  font-size: clamp(1rem, 5vw + 1rem, 6rem);
  color: white;
  font-family: Hiragino;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>The College Dropout</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./main.css">

</head>

<body>


  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-default">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="../index.html">Home</a>
            <a href="">About Me</a>
            <a href="">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>

    <div class="image-container">
      <img class="image-style" src="../assets/images/college-dropout.jpg" alt="the-college-dropout">
      <h1 class="title-style">The College Dropout</h1>
      <h2 class="subtitle-style">2004, 21 songs, 1 h 16 min</h2>

    </div>
  </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a new div containing only the title and subtitle like so in your html:

```
        <div class="image-container">
            <img class="image-style" src="../assets/images/college-dropout.jpg" alt="the-college-dropout">
            <div>
              <h1 class="title-style">The College Dropout</h1>
              <h2 class="subtitle-style">2004, 21 songs, 1 h 16 min</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
```

let me know if this works

Comment: i see, ill update my answer to another solution

Comment: I can't believe it was this simple, thanks man, I overcomplicated the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Grids)

```
.image-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: clamp(200px, 50%, 400px) auto;
}

.image-style {
  grid-row-start: span 2;
}
```

```css
.container {
  /* background: rgb(65, 18, 24); */
  background: rgb(65, 18, 24) linear-gradient(
    0deg,
    rgba(65, 18, 24, 1) 0%,
    rgba(232, 152, 46, 1) 100%
  );
  padding-top: 2rem;
  padding-bottom: 5rem;
}

.image-container {
  /* display: flex; */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: clamp(200px, 50%, 400px) auto;
  margin-left: 2rem;
  align-items: center;
}

.image-style {
  grid-row-start: span 2;
  width: clamp(200px, 50%, 400px);
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.image-container .title-style {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  font-size: clamp(1rem, 5vw + 1rem, 6rem);
  color: white;
  font-family: Hiragino;
  /* display: block; */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

    <div class="image-container">
        <img class="image-style" src="../assets/images/college-dropout.jpg" alt="the-college-dropout">
        <h1 class="title-style">The College Dropout</h1>
        <h2 class="subtitle-style">2004, 21 songs, 1 h 16 min</h2>
    </div>

</div>
```